# What does "error reading login count from pmvarrun" mean?

Tags: lightdm, log

I have the above mentioned error in my

/var/log/auth.log

file and just try to figure out if this is a harmelss statement. As far as I understand does pmvarrun tells the system how many active session (e.g. logins) a user has on the system.

Full output of auth.log

```
Jan 24 17:44:42 P835 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 24 17:44:42 P835 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jan 24 17:44:49 P835 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "user"
Jan 24 17:44:51 P835 dbus[1289]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.31" (uid=104 pid=1882 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.17" (uid=0 pid=1561 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:691): received order to close things
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:693): No volumes to umount
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: command: 'pmvarrun' '-u' 'user' '-o' '-1' 
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<pre>: (ruid/rgid=0/0, e=0/0)
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<post>: (ruid/rgid=0/0, e=0/0)
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:438): error reading login count from pmvarrun
Jan 24 17:45:04 P835 lightdm: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:728): pam_mount execution complete
Jan 24 17:45:08 P835 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user user by (uid=0)
Jan 24 17:45:08 P835 lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jan 24 17:45:25 P835 polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.54 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 24 17:45:47 P835 dbus[1289]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.59" (uid=1000 pid=4748 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.17" (uid=0 pid=1561 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!